# How to convert the string that contains the superscript(m²) to normal string like m2 in C++

Tags: c++, superscript

In my project, I need to convert the string that contains the superscript - m² to the string m2.

My project accepts unit of measure which includes meter square (m²) or meter cube (m³). And I need to convert the superscripts to a normal integer or string in order to further process the input data.
However, at this moment am unable find any thing in C++ that does this for me.

The application is in C++ and we are using CComBSTR to store the string.

The ideal output would be m2 for m² and m3 for m³ and so on...

Any suggestions

Comment: There are only ten superscript digits. You could just search/replace for each one.

Comment: How to find that character is superscript, I could not find appropriate function. Please guide me.

Comment: In class `std::string` are 105 memberfunctions, a large part dedicated to finding and replacing. I have problems imagining how you can *not* find anything suitable.

Comment: But we are using CComBSTR in our project not std::string.

Comment: That's even easier. CComBSTR is already Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

A `CComBSTR` is just a wrapper for a `BSTR`. That in turn is a `WCHAR*`, which maps to C++ type `wchar_t*`. Since you're on Windows, you have to know that `WCHAR` is UTF-16.

That means you need to look for `wchar_t(0x00B2)` and `wchar_t(0x00B3)`. `std::find` can do that, just pass it the begin and end of your `BSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the key point is the character encoding. A superscript 2 is not an ascii char. They have dedicated unicode chars (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts, with values in range 0x207x, except 2 and 3) and they are typically encoded with 16 bits. If you have a std::string then a character then they are probably encoded in UTF-8, which means more than one char per character (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

There is a lot to read, but at the end it's quite easy. You just need to search for a substring (che UTF-8 of superscript 2 and 3)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. The application which we have is in C++, where we store the string in CComBSTR.  Please guide me to resolve this issue.